# React.js having state based on other state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into some problems with React.js and the state not being immediately set when calling setState().  I'm not sure if there are better ways to approach this, or if it really is just a shortcoming of React.  I have two state variables, one of which is based on the other. (Fiddle of original problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/4415/ you can see in the logs that it's not set right away when you click the button)

```
setAlarmTime: function(time) {
  this.setState({ alarmTime: time });
  this.checkAlarm();
},
checkAlarm: function() {
  this.setState({
    alarmSet: this.state.alarmTime > 0 && this.state.elapsedTime < this.state.alarmTime
  });
}, ...
```

When calling `setAlarmTime`, since `this.state.alarmTime` isn't updated immediately, the following call to `checkAlarm` sets `alarmSet` based on the previous value of `this.state.alarmTime` and is therefore incorrect.

I solved this by moving the call to `checkAlarm` into the callback of `setState` in `setAlarmTime`, but having to keep track of what state is actually 'correct' and try to fit everything into callbacks seems ridiculous:

```
setAlarmTime: function(time) {
  this.setState({ alarmTime: time }, this.checkAlarm);
}
```

Is there a better way to go about this?  There are a few other places in my code which I reference state I just set and now I'm unsure as to when I can actually trust the state!

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, [setState](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) is asynchronous, so `this.state` won't be updated immediately. Here are the [unit tests](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0a1c5dad67734f3da664967e0b6fb6f26fbeef88/src/core/__tests__/ReactUpdates-test.js) for batching, which might explain some of the details.

In the example above, `alarmSet` is data computed from the `alarmTime` and `elapsedTime` state. Generally speaking, computed data shouldn't be stored in the state of the object, instead it should be computed as-needed as part of the render method. There is a section [What *Shouldn’t* Go in State?](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state) at the bottom of the Interactivity and Dynamic UIs docs which gives examples of things like this which shouldn't go in state, and the [What Components Should Have State?](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-components-should-have-state) section explains some of the reasons why this might be a good idea.

Comment: In most cases it does make sense to have the state be as minimal as possible and to just recompute things in the render function since `this.state` will be completely up to date then.  However, I don't think this works in my case, as this component actually has it's own update loop (using setInterval) which has to update and check its state at every tick. Therefore it's not guaranteed that `render` will have run in between ticks.  As a workaround I implemented a wrapper on `React.createClass` that tracks it's own state. I'll add it as an answer here too http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/4448/

Comment: There's a good article about the Flux architecture for RectJS here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html One of the things they do is separate out the "complicated" state from the React components in the view layer, that could apply here too. Instead of putting the setInterval in the view, that would probably be something which happens in the stores, then whenever the stores update it would trigger a view re-render. The stores could be plain JS objects, without the async behaviour of setState.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Comment: Wondering if it'd be a good idea if we can move the dependent state to useEffect , that way change in the seed state will trigger update of everything else.

Comment: my take away from question is : computed data shouldn't be stored in the state of the object!

Answer (score 4):

As Douglas stated, it's generally not a good idea to keep computed state in `this.state`, but instead to recompute it each time in the component's `render` function, since the state will have been updated by that point.

However this won't work for me, as my component actually has its own update loop which needs to check and possibly update its state at every tick. Since we cannot count on `this.state` to have been updated at every tick, I created a workaround that wraps `React.createClass` and adds it's own internal state tracking. (Requires jQuery for $.extend) (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/4448/)

```
var Utils = new function() {
  this.createClass = function(object) {
    return React.createClass(
      $.extend(
        object,
        {
          _state: object.getInitialState ? object.getInitialState() : {},
          _setState: function(newState) {
            $.extend(this._state, newState);
            this.setState(newState);
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

For any components where you need up-to-date state outside of the render function, just replace the call to `React.createClass` with `Utils.createClass`.

You'll also have to change all `this.setState` calls with `this._setState` and `this.state` calls with `this._state`.

One last consequence of doing this is that you'll lose the auto-generated `displayName` property in your component.  This is due to the jsx transformer replacing

`var anotherComponent = React.createClass({`

with

`var anotherComponent = React.createClass({displayName: 'anotherComponent'`.

To get around this, you'll just have to manually add in the displayName property to your objects.

Hope this helps

Comment: A simpler way could be to store your state entirely outside of react and pass it to react as props - then your state is always up to date, and react may not have reconciled yet which doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure if this was the case when question was asked, though now the second parameter of `this.setState(stateChangeObject, callback)` takes an optional callback function, so can do this:

```
setAlarmTime: function(time) {
  this.setState({ alarmTime: time }, this.checkAlarm);
},
checkAlarm: function() {
  this.setState({
    alarmSet: this.state.alarmTime > 0 && this.state.elapsedTime < this.state.alarmTime
  });
}, ...
```

Comment: You should never use `this.state` inside `this.setState(...)`. Because `this.setState(...)` is asynchronous (most of the time) you can not predict what the content of `this.state` is at the time of execution.

`this.setState(prevState => ({
    alarmSet: prevState.alarmTime > 0 && prevState.elapsedTime < prevState.alarmTime
  }));`

would be the right way to do it.