# How do you go about state property depending on another property (from same class)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder how should I approach properties in component's state that depend on another property, for example:

```
class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mainProperty: 1,
      something: {
        dependingOnMainProperty: `foo${this.state.mainProperty}bar`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I would like `dependingOnMainProperty` to be automatically updated when I change `mainProperty` through `setState`. Should I write a function for that or is there some other solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js having state based on other state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145857/react-js-having-state-based-on-other-state)

Comment: State is a simple object. It's not observed or computed. Just plain values. I would recommend you to use `mobx` for global state management. It works great with react, and does have the ability to observe values & compute values based on other values..

Answer (score 0):

You may do with getters and setters as follows;

```js
class Component {
  constructor(...props){
    props.forEach(prop => this[prop] = "whatever");
  }
}

class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.state = {
      something: {
        __mp__: "tester",
        dependingOnMainProperty: `foo${this.mainProperty}bar`,
        get mainProperty(){
          return this.__mp__;
        },
        set mainProperty(v){
          this.__mp__ = v;
          this.dependingOnMainProperty = `foo ${v} bar`;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

var s = new Sample("a", "b");
s.state.something.mainProperty = "hello";
console.log(s.state.something.dependingOnMainProperty);
```